# Are all the Under-19 players allowed to play only one world cup?

Tags: rules, cricket, cricket-world-cup

I heard Sourav Ganguly say that the Indian Under-19 players are allowed to play in only one World Cup, while he was commentating in the India vs Australia U-19 World Cup match in New Zealand.

So, is this rule applicable for the Indian players only or is this an universal rule for the Under 19 players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be for Indian Players only because the BCCI has decided that players who have represented India in one Under-19 World Cup cannot take part in another edition of the tournament, even if they meet the age criteria to do so.

Apart from this, the BCCI also passed a rule that players can only play a maximum of two season of Under-19 cricket. This is one of the many ways the board is trying to rectify the situation of age fudging.

Before this rule, a number of players have represented India at more than one Under-19 World Cup. Three members of their squad in 2016 - Avesh Khan, Sarfaraz Khan and Ricky Bhui - had also played in the 2014 edition. Examples from the past include Ravindra Jadeja (2006 and 2008) and Vijay Zol (2012 and 2014).

---

References:

1. [India players barred from playing multiple U-19 World Cups](http://www.espncricinfo.com/story/_/id/16473396/india-players-barred-playing-multiple-u-19-world-cups)
2. [BCCI prohibits Indian players from playing multiple U-19 World Cups](https://www.sportskeeda.com/cricket/bcci-prohibits-indian-players-playing-multiple-u-19-world-cups)
3. [BCCI issues guidelines to state associations on age fudging](http://www.espn.in/cricket/story/_/id/16859383/bcci-issues-guidelines-state-associations-age-fudging)

Comment: Afghanistan Cricket Board also employs the rule that a player may only play in one ICC U19 World Cup. This is in order to provide more opportunities for a larger group of players and to broaden the base of cricketers in Afghanistan. Although Rashid Khan is eligible for the ICC U19 World Cup, he is not playing this edition, partly for this reason given by the Afghanistan Cricket Board.